# unable view li content on small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am using bootstrap nav-tab it is looking fine on big screens but on small screens it suddenly not showing the li content .

[image]

[image]

and my code is

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#lost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> Help</a></li>
</ul>

.nav-tabs{
    border: none;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active 
{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00f6c7;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a{
    border: none;      
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, 
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus{
    border: none;
}
```

any help

Comment: You haven't even attempted to ask a question.

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the li is not displaying on mobile that is my question it was like exactly less than 780px width -Daniel Tate

Comment: There's not enough to go on. It's not a question of just the ul, it's the entire div and all the html and styles that go with it, plus any media queries.